# scripts.js not doing anything in Zen subtheme

Tags: javascript, theming

In a Drupal 7 site I have a Zen subtheme. The info file specifies scripts/script.js. I tested out some simple jQuery in the scratchpad and it works. But if I paste it into script.js, clear the caches, rebuild the theme registry, etc. when I reload the page, there's nothing. Even if the only content of the file is `alert('debug text');` it's as if the file were just totally empty.

I don't know what else to do besides clearing all the caches, and I don't know where else to try debugging.

Comment: Can you switch off JS aggregation and inspect the markup to see if your JS file is included (and if so follow the link via the browser to check the JS file is accessible)? Are you aware you should use [behaviors](http://drupal.org/node/756722#behaviors) to add JS to a page?

Comment: JS aggregation is off. script.js is not anywhere in the markup. I was not aware of behaviors.

Comment: You definitely have the zen subtheme active?!

Comment: And if you're using the Overlay, beware that it uses a different theme by default.

Comment: I am an idiot. It was commented out in the info file. Leaving this question in existence becaue the behaviors comment was useful.